# TypeScript how to solve - 'require' call may be converted to an import

Tags: typescript

In my Typescript file I am importing two packages from node_modules and one json file:

```
const axios = require('axios').default;
const cors = require('cors')
const creds = require('../utils/credentials.json');
```

There are no syntax errors highlighted for the first line, however the second and third line shows this message:

```
'require' call may be converted to an import.ts(80005)
```

If I follow the suggestion I end up with this

```
const axios = require('axios').default;
import cors from 'cors';
import creds from '../utils/credentials.json';
```

Which I do not want because it combines `require` with `import` in the same file.

Another issue is that the syntax highlighting for unused variables only shows when I use `import`.

I have already added `"resolveJsonModule": true,` to my compiler options but that doesn't seem to change anything.

If I remove the `.default` from line 1 then I get the suggestion to change all lines to use `import`:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import cors from 'cors';
import creds from '../utils/credentials.json';
```

This way it works fine and I also get the syntax highlighting for unused variables.

Can someone please explain why there are suggested changes for switching to use `import` and not `require`?

Comment: `import axios from 'axios';` is importing the default-export by default
But you can also import only needed function/variables like
`import { neededFunction } from 'axios';`

Comment: Why *what exactly* is hapenning? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Updated last part. Want to understand why Typescript is complaining about the use of `require` but not `require('package').default` or `import`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`require` is CommonJS way to import modules or other js files.
In typescript it should be written as

```
import cors = require("cors");
```

(which transpiles to `const cors = require("cors");`)

`import` is a more modern way to import modules or other js files.

If your `tsconfig`s `module` is `commonjs` then all your `import`s will be converted to `require`.
Hovewer, `require`s won't be converted to `import`s, making `import x = require(x)` incompatible with `module: 'ESNext'` option

---

So, why TS80005 does not work with `.default`?
That's because there is no clean way to convert is

If you change the code to

```
const { default: axios } = require('axios');
```

then you'll get TS80005 to convert it to

```
import { default as axios } from 'axios';
```

This works well, but you may want to change it to classical default import

```
import axios from 'axios';
```

The ES modules, unlike CommonJS modules, return their `default` if imported directly.
If you want to get the whole scope like you would get from CommonJS ones, you'll need

```
import * as axiosAll from 'axios';
const axios = axiosAll.default
```

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for, thank you!